# Difference in seconds between current row and previous row and store the value in separate column when order ID also matches using google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to take the difference in seconds between current row and previous row and store the value in separate column when order ID also matches using google bigquery.
PS: row # 4 take difference based on row # 7 as that is the next available order id
(Date field is not string but timestamp) in my table test:product.tab1
eg:

```
Date                    Order  Difference In Seconds
2016-05-31 11:46:54 UTC 14567   11
2016-05-31 11:46:43 UTC 14567   19
2016-05-31 11:46:24 UTC 14567   20
2016-05-31 11:46:04 UTC 14567    4
2016-05-31 11:46:54 UTC 22455   11
2016-05-31 11:46:43 UTC 24567    0
2016-05-31 11:46:00 UTC 14567    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below
And I would recommend you to check out [Window functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions)

```
SELECT
  DATE, id,
  IFNULL(TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(DATE)) -   
         TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(prev_date))
    , 0) AS Difference_In_Seconds
FROM (
  SELECT  
    DATE, id,
    LEAD(DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS prev_date
  FROM
    (SELECT STRING(DATE) AS DATE, id FROM [test:product.tab1] )
)
ORDER BY id, DATE DESC
```

Comment: I tried to optimize such query
SELECT  
    DATE, id,
    date - LEAD(DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS diff
  FROM
    (SELECT STRING(DATE) AS date, id FROM [test:product.tab1]  order by id date desc)
but I received an error - Missing function in Analytic Expression, Do you know why I cant do that?